# Carousel asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC, Today I tried to install a new bootstrap them , I got all stuff working except Carousel is not showing.

this is my bundle class:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));


        //bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
        //          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
        //          "~/Content/site.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
             "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
             "~/Content/modern-bussiness.css",
                "~/Content/site.css"));

    }
}
```

And this is my index

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
```

and this is the function:

```
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})
</script>
```

Is any one there to help.

Comment: Are there any errors in the debug console?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs
[Jcarrousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/installation.html)

you need to add

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jcarrousel").Include(
                "~/path/to/jquery.jcarousel.js"));
```